# CORBA::ORB_init exception

Tags: c++, corba, ace, tao

I am adding ACE / TAO as a component to a large project which is written in C and C++. I received an .IOR file from the server, and I use the .IOR file when calling CORBA::ORB_init(argc, argv)

I constructed my own argc and argv as followed

```
int argc = 2;
char *argv[2] = { 0 };
argv[0] = "-k";
argv[1] = "D:\\IOR\\test.ior";

CORBA::ORB_var orb = CORBA::ORB_init(argc, argv);
```

When I call ORB_init, I get a "Debug Assertion Failed!", and it points to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp line: 908

```
_ASSERTE(is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use));
```

CORBA::ORB_init was called very early in the code, so there isn't many things that can go wrong.
Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

- You got a heap corruption indicated by the assertion in debug_heap

  - when you run this in the debugger, you should see (Call Stack) *where* the assertion triggers, possibly enabling you to pinpoint the problem.

That being said, `ORB_init(argc, argv)` is supposed to get the C command line arguments and parse them. That means `argc` and `argv` should probably abide by the [rules for these arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=msvc-170):

> `argc`
> An integer that contains the count of arguments that follow in
> argv. The argc parameter is always greater than or equal to 1.
>
> `argv`
> An array of null-terminated strings representing command-line
> arguments entered by the user of the program. By convention, `argv[0]`
> is the command with which the program is invoked. `argv[1]` is the first
> command-line argument. The last argument from the command line is
> `argv[argc - 1]`, and `argv[argc]` is always `NULL`.

Try:

```
int argc = 3;
char *argv[4];
argv[0] = "program";
argv[1] = "-k";
argv[2] = "D:\\IOR\\test.ior";
argv[3] = nullptr;
```